# how to extract string list values in ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

In controller

```
 List<String> currectTime = userService1.getUserCurrectTime(time,hash);
```

I need to extract each value from the ajax success responce.

```
$( ".dropdownlist" ).change(function() {
    var time=$('#dropdownlist').val();
    var hash=$('#hash').val();
    alert(time+hash);

    var savedata = {    
        time:time,
        hash:hash
    }; 

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'../test',
        data:savedata,    
        error:function() {
            alert("error");
        },
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data);
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        }
    });  
});
```

If I alert the response data I see the below

```
["28-12-2014 01:10:45 NST","30-12-2014 02:40:35 NST","06-11-2014 16:10:45 NST"]
```

How can I get these values separately.

Comment: `$.each(obj, function(index, value){console.log(value)})` method would be useful or fixed index like `obj[0]`

Comment: I don't understand if you need to loop the object or retrieve the date, time and tz separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply loop over your object.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);

for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) { 
    console.log(obj[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(obj, function(i,data){
    alert(data);

});
```